# Not able to see and modify Contentversion or File details like title and Description

Tags: lightning, files, contentdocument

I'm facing a very strange issue, i have two orgs, in one of the salesforce org everything is working fine which is a Dev org. another one is scratch org. in the scratch org when I upload the file the file is uploaded under Opportunity (as part of Contentversion), but I'm not able to see the details of the file, which is title and description. It seems to be a permission issue, although I checked and try to provide every necessary permission related to Contentversion and ContentDocument.

[image]

Comment: Check for page layout of File. In that you may missing the details component.

Comment: Check if its going into Notes & Attachment. Also check the page layout.

Comment: @MohitKulkarni, Well I checked, I can see the files, also able to upload new version, the issue is with viewing the file details or edit those properties. as you can see from the screenshot, the details section is empty.